# How to handle ElementsAfterSelf() when there are no more elements?

Tags: c#, xml, debugging

I have an XML file. I am using a foreach loop to check the content of all the child elements. When I'm at the last element and call `ElementsAfterSelf()` it returns a non null list, but in the debugger in VS, it says' "Enumerations yields no values." I'm Ok with that since there are no values but how do I check that so i don't get a nullreference exception?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> tempElement = xUserInfo.ElementsAfterSelf();
if (tempElement.Elements().Count() != null)
```

//but this is always true even if there are no more elements

then when i try

```
tempElement.First()
```

it throws an exception... What can I check so I don't get an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Any` returns true if there are any elements in the sequence, which is to say that it's not empty.

If you are only interested in the first value the alternative is to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`, if the sequence might be empty, and to check the result of that for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tempElement.Elements().Count() > 0)
```

Try this instead. Null refers to an empty data cell. Count() returning zero to a data cell is different and not null which could be why your if statement is always true.